# Why two HTTP and TCP addresses can use the same port and two IPC addresses cannot use the same named pipe?

Tags: tcp, named-pipes

What I think of a port is: Whenever a message arrives to a machine, it is copied to a memory area which is mapped to the port specified and the concerned application or service is notified that a message has arrived for it.

If this is true, then what happens if two messages arrive for two different services listening on the same port ? ( either http or tcp )

And why can not two named pipe addresses use the same named pipe ?

Comment: What do you mean by "named pipe addresses"?

Comment: In general, your analysis is misleading: only one service at a time can listen for tcp/ip connections on a particular port, whatever the application protocol.

Comment: Named pipe addresses mean IPC addresses.

Comment: Perhaps you need to clarify what OS platform you are talking about. `Named pipes` means different things on Unix and Windows, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP identifies "connections" via a tuple of { local ip, local port, remote ip, remote port }.  Therefore, since each incoming connection has a different remote ip/port pair, your local machine can distinguish between them.

HTTP uses TCP for its transport.  Thus, an HTTP port *is* a TCP port.

If you've ever had your machine get a new IP address while you had connections open, you'll note that they break the first time they send any data out since the remote host does not recognize the (new) address and sends a RST response.

A pipe has only its name to distinguish it so there is only one "connection" no matter how many writers it has.

Comment: Minor correction:  The connection is identified by a 5-tuple; I left out "protocol" (i.e. tcp/udp are separate).

Comment: `there is only one 'connection' no matter how many writers it has.` - on a Windows OS, this is *totally untrue*. There is one name, potentially many pipe instances (i.e. client-server connections). Just like TCP.

Comment: I'm an UN*X person...  I didn't even know that Windows had named pipes.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your description is one way to handle incoming messages.

In the case of two web sites listening on the same port, there is *one* web server listening on that port, which then looks at the http host header to find the correct web site to forward the request to.

The same is true for named pipes, the RPC listener listens on the TCP port, and then finds out that it is a named pipe message and then forwards the message to the right named pipe.

Comment: It means a named pipe also uses a port for receiving messages ?

Comment: Yes, named pipes is a high level protocol, which is implemented using RPC calls, which are implemented either directly on TCP or previously often on NetBIOS, which could be run on top of TCP or NetBEUI.